# How to give bottom shadow to UIView in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview

[image]

## This I want

[image]

## My Code

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowView.bounds).cgPath
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grey.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

I want to implement exactly same shadow in my UIVIew. When I run my app with above code it spread over 4 sides. Notice : the shadow thin at both edges and bold at centre.

Comment: Your shadow should be red  ? I am not able to find red colour

Comment: which colour you see? I give opacity as 0.5. Not bothered about colour.

Comment: Gray color ? around the  picture

Comment: I want to build the shadow shape only not the colour

Comment: I give red for testing...

Comment: @Alwin According to me you are talking about the little curve below the image?

Comment: @Alwin You can ask your designer to get that particular type image (black curve) and from our side use `imageview` and show that image under the main image. From user side it doest make any difference.

Comment: can you done it programatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try creating custom path:

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath()
shadowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: someView.bounds.origin.x, y: someView.frame.size.height))
shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: someView.bounds.width / 2, y: someView.bounds.height + 7.0))
shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: someView.bounds.width, y: someView.bounds.height))
shadowPath.close()

shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

This gives similiar results, try to customize points positions and other values to match your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Slight change to @jonaszmclaren to give a rectangular shadow:

```
func makeBottomShadow(forView view: UIView, shadowHeight: CGFloat = 5) {
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath()
    shadowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width, y: view.bounds.height))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width, y: view.bounds.height + shadowHeight))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height + shadowHeight))
    shadowPath.close()

    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This out**

**IBOutlet**

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwShadow: UIView!
```

**In ViewdidLoad**

```
vwShadow.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
vwShadow.layer.masksToBounds = false
vwShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0 , height: 5.0)
vwShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
vwShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
```

Comment: This is not I want.

Comment: as you have told above, you want to shadow your view at bottom. this is the code snippet for it.

Comment: I want shadow only bottom. Your code spreads shadow to right, left and top slightly. That not I need.

Comment: it can done programatically. @jonaszmclaren helped me for achieve that.

Comment: This adds shadow to all 4 sides.